# React Native get ios device language

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get the current locale from ios devices.

I followed [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) when I created my project and I'm using expo.

I tried the following code

```
 if (Platform.OS === "android") {
     langRegionLocale = NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier || "";
 } else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
     langRegionLocale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale || "";
 }
```

and **it worked for android**, but when tested on an iPhone, it did not work and said **SettingsManager was undefined** when i logged it.

How can I get the current locale for ios **without ejecting or using [AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n)**?

If possible I would like to use something that is built in.

Below is my **package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "demoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0",
    "jest-expo": "^21.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expo [Util API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/util.html) has a method for getting device locale.

> [`Expo.Util.getCurrentLocaleAsync()`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/util.html#expoutilgetcurrentlocaleasync)
>
> Returns the current device
>   locale as a string.